# Android::Where can get voice call of PCM data/buffers before pass to earpieces?

Tags: android, call, voice, telephony, pcm

I want to add some audio effects into a voice call before passing it to the earpieces/earphone.
I tried to add an effect in audio_hw_hal.cpp on a PCM buffer, but without success.
Because the voice call procedure is not going through this module.

Could you let me know where I can process the voice call of PCM data before playing the sound through the earpieces/earphone?